# Conditional aggregate dependent on multiple columns

Tags: r

I am trying to aggregate data dependant on multiple columns and the aggregation is a function of another column. Below is a sample of my dataset:

```
STATE    NAICS     ENTRSIZE     FIRM
0        11        2            14869
0        11        3            3472
0        11        4            1656
0        11        6            1119
0        11        9            84
0        21        2            12623
0        21        3            3203
1        11        2            14869
1        11        7            54
1        11        9            12
```

What I would like to achieve is for each STATE NAICS pair sum the FIRM value dependant on the ENTRSIZE value. Basically, I would like to aggregate all ENTRSIZE of 2, 3, 4, 6 to "SMALL", 7 to "MEDIUM" and 9 to "LARGE" so my final data should look like:

```
STATE    NAICS     ENTRSIZE     FIRM
0        11        SMALL        21116
0        11        LARGE        84
0        21        SMALL        15826
1        11        SMALL        14869
1        11        MEDIUM       54
1        11        LARGE        12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> df %>% mutate(ENTRSIZE = case_when( ENTRSIZE  %in% 2:6 ~ 'SMALL', ENTRSIZE == 7 ~ 'MEDIUM', TRUE ~ 'LARGE')) %>% group_by(STATE, NAICS, ENTRSIZE) %>% summarise(FIRM = sum(FIRM))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'STATE', 'NAICS' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   STATE, NAICS [3]
  STATE NAICS ENTRSIZE  FIRM
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1     0    11 LARGE       84
2     0    11 SMALL    21116
3     0    21 SMALL    15826
4     1    11 LARGE       12
5     1    11 MEDIUM      54
6     1    11 SMALL    14869
```